# Aurora Serverless with API Gateway and Lambda is timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm building a new project with totally serverless environment in AWS

I picked up API Gateway + Lambda + Aurora Serverless inside a VPC but Aurora cold start plus Lambda cold start is greater than API Gateway timeout of 29 secods

Is it possible to make any improvement to avoid such time out ? Anyone has experienced this already ?

Answer (score 0):

Aurora Serverless V2 can easily scale from few to thousands of transactions in less than a second.

If you are using Aurora Serverless V1, we can set a minimum ACU to 1 and `Don't pause compute capacity after consecutive minutes of inactivity`(there is some cost)

Lambda cold starts can be avoided with [provisioned concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html).